# Input File em diretorio especifico

Tags: javascript, input

Preciso criar um sistema para anexar arquivos que serão utilizado via Web para anexar ligação. Porem as ligações ficam salvas em um servidor local a parte (\192.168.0.6\VOZ\voz).

Quando clico em **anexar** ele abre a minha pasta local e não consigo definir para ele abrir o servidor especifico quando clico em **buscar arquivo** ou coisa do gênero.

Existe algum meio de eu definir qual diretório ele vai abrir automaticamente? para eu poder fazer esse sistema para anexar ligações, pois não tem como os operadores que utilizaram o sistema toda vez procurar o diretório.

Comment: Da uma lida ai: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17420736/3956218, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, vou utilizar de mapeamento de unidade mesmo para facilitar a busca.

Comment: Uma pergunta, você upa os arquivos como? porque não define o caminho desse upload com a linguagem server-side que utiliza?

Comment: Os arquivos na verdade estão em um programa de ligação (Intelbras) e é salvo em um servidor especifico para isso. Um segundo sistema (em outro servidor) é onde os operadores adicionam as informações. Desta forma quando adicionado uma informação eles teriam que adicionar a ligação referente aquela informação que se encontra em outro servidor.